# Logout script is not working

Tags: php, mysql

Please help with my logout script. I am sorry for dumb mistakes I am very new to php. Please provide me with details and examples of how to fix this. Thank you so much.

Login Page: There are 4 types of users. Each user will get a separate home page.

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('common/config.php');


if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $fetched = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if ($fetched['user_type'] == "admin")
        {
           header('location: adminhomepage.php');
        }
        else if ($fetched['user_type'] == "po")
        {
           header('location: pohomepage.php');
        }
        else if ($fetched['user_type'] == "pw")
        {
           header('location: pwhomepage.php');
        }
        else if ($fetched['user_type'] == "ps")
        {
           header('location: pshomepage.php');
        }
        else
        {
           header('location: invalid.php');
           exit();
        }
}
?>
```

Home Page: For instance this is the admin home page.

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['username'] !== 1))
{
    header('Location: login.php');
}

?>
```

Logout Page

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] =0;

?>
```

Logout Button

```
<form action = "logout.php">
     <input id="logoutbutton" type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
```

Comment: Add `session_start()` in logout page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## logout page

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['susername']);
    $_SESSION['susername'] = "";
    session_destroy();

    header("location:index.php");
?>
```

### login.php

```
session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['uname']) == "")
    {               
        require_once('index.php');
    }

    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];
    $_SESSION['susername'] = $user_name; // or other value
```

Comment: There should be no changes brought to the home page? I cant login to the homepage now. Keeps receiving the login page.

Comment: you want to only logout script. in homw page set any session and the last destory it.but if you want to page back problem then i give you login login then if you logout and back then it required login first.

Answer (score 0):

logout page -

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] =0;

?>
```

you have to start the `session` first before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `logout.php` please update this code...

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {
           unset($_SESSION['username']);
           header('Location: login.php');
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use unset($_SESSION['susername']) or session_destroy

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

With your new information, it's clear you never actually set the $_SESSION['username'] value.

```
if ($fetched['user_type'] == "admin")
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('location: adminhomepage.php');
}
else if ($fetched['user_type'] == "po")
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('location: pohomepage.php');
}
else if ($fetched['user_type'] == "pw")
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('location: pwhomepage.php');
}
else if ($fetched['user_type'] == "ps")
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('location: pshomepage.php');
}
else 
{
    header('location: invalid.php');
}
exit();
```

Your problem is your comparison.

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] != 1)
```

This is true if $_SESSION['username'] is not set, null, a string, false, etc...

This might be more what you are looking for.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && is_string($_SESSION['username']) && strlen($_SESSION['username']))
```

And you need to fix your SQL injection problem here

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'";
```

Escape variables with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or use PDO with proper prepared statements.

You should also store passwords as [hashes with password_hash()](http://php.net/password_hash). Fetch the user, compare stored hash to password with [password_verify](http://php.net/password_verify).

```
if (!password_verify($password, $fetched["password"])) {/* wrong password, show error or something */}
```

Comment: I cant seem to login to the home page. The login page keeps refreshing when I enter login.

Comment: @Zazu you have to set the value of $_SESSION['username'] to something somewhere before you do your check to see if it is set.

Comment: Please give me an example of what you mean. I am very new to this. Sorry.

Comment: @Zazu noone can help you without more information about your code. Where in your flow do you process the login form and set the $_SESSION['username'] value? I suggest you make it a new question.

Comment: @Zazu added a better reply for your new details.

Comment: I still have the same issue about not being able to login to the homepage. The homepage keeps redirecting me back to the login page.

Comment: @Zazu you have not posted the login form